# Remote Desktop without using IP address but with a domain name (URL)

Tags: remote-desktop, rdp

I have a VPS (say, 13.15.65.5) with Windows 2019 and I want to access it by using the Remote Desktop service with a subdomain without using the IP of the VPS.

I configured all settings for the subdomain by using the IP of the VPS in Cloudflare. Then I checked it by pinging the URL and received the messages "Reply from..." and "Success 100%".

But still, I cannot access the server by using that URL with Remote Desktop. Please help me to resolve this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of how things is set up in CloudFlare? Is the IP shown when pinging the IP of the VM?

Comment: Thank you. Ok, I will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You proxy your subdomain through Cloudflare. That only works for HTTP(S).

For RDP, you need a DNS record pointing to your IP, so turn off the *Proxy status*.

Comment: Super simple. It works. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @chandrasiri Please consider accepting the answer if it solved your problem. Otherwise it'll pop up again looking for new answers every now and then.

Comment: I accept your answer. But I don't know how to make your answer "acceptable". May I know the way to do it?

Comment: There's a small check mark next to the answer. You click that to [accept the answer](https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers).